# success/error message for insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

when the info is successfully inserted, it's displaying the error message and saying that it's a duplicate entry for a primary key...I can't figure out why!

```
<?
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pw=$_POST['pw'];

mysql_connect('***','***','***');
@mysql_select_db('***') or die('Unable to select database');

$query = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('','$email','$pw')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_query($query))
{
    echo 'success';
}
else
{
    echo 'failure' .mysql_error();
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Answer (score 6):

**You are executing the query twice**: first, in `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and second, in `if(mysql_query($query))`. So the second time the query executes the record is already there and thus the insertion fails.

Comment: this makes sense...what is the best way to fix it?

Comment: Just does not called twice.

Answer (score 2):

You are executing same query twice.

```
$query_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if ($query_result) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'failure' . mysql_error();
}
```

Write this way, hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete this code from your php script and it will be fine.

```
if(mysql_query($query))
{
    echo 'success';
}
else
{
    echo 'failure' .mysql_error();
}
```

You make it running error twice in a time. You can also use `mysql_affected_rows()` to make sure the data is executed in database server. Return a string type value.

```
<?
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pw=$_POST['pw'];

mysql_connect('***','***','***');
@mysql_select_db('***') or die('Unable to select database');

$query = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('','$email','$pw')";
if(mysql_query($query))
{
    echo 'Data executed : '.mysql_affected_rows();
}
else
{
    echo 'failure' .mysql_error();
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Good luck and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pw=$_POST['pw'];

 $alerts = array();

if (trim($_POST['email']) == '') {
   $alerts[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'> Enter your Email! </div>"; }
if (trim($_POST['pw']) == '') {
   $alerts[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'> Enter your PW! </div>"; }

if (!count($alerts)) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO test_table (email, pw) VALUES ('".$email."', '".$pw."')";
   mysqli_query($this->conn, $query) or die (mysqli_connect_error());
   return ['success' => true];
} else {
   return ['success' => false, 'alert_m' => implode($alerts)."<br>"];
}
```

Comment: 3 yo post, I think this answer is useless. Or at least not necessary.